# Is it too late to plant roses in the ground in November

Tags: plant-care, container-gardening, roses

I bought some David Austin roses earlier this year and put them into containers to test. The reason is that my yards are very shady so I wanted to see if the "spot" works due to many pine trees around and this is my new house in Pacific Northwest so I am unfamiliar with the sun direction.

Anyways, I got the location identified and they did well during summer. But I totally forgot to put them down in the ground. Now it is November 9th. Is it too late to dig holes and plant them into the ground at this point? Or should I wait until last frost date. I guess that'd be March next year.

Thanks,

Comment: I have no idea about the Pacific Northwest climate, but in general you can plant them any time the roses are dormant and the ground is not frozen.

Comment: I don't know what the weather's like in your area either - do you get early and always very cold winters? Have you had any frosts yet? If not, what;'s the usual first frost date, as well as average winter temperature? Knowing your USDA zone would also help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plant them in the ground. Unless you have a greenhouse , they would be more likely to die in pots over winter. In garden zones 5 and 8 , I have never had a problem with planting something in the winter . And hybrid tea roses ( assuming that is what you have ) tolerate cold weather. In zone 5 , I started cuttings in the ground; as winter came I put an aquarium over them for protection , a mini green house , at outside temperature. Mid winter , I brushed a foot of snow off the aquarium and found a bloom.